# Source for Kinnock quote: 'fortunate in her enemies'

Tags: united-kingdom, reference-request

I've heard Neil Kinnock quoted many times as having said that Margaret Thatcher was 'fortunate in her enemies' (i.e. part of her success was due to her opponents, including Kinnock). However, I can't find the original source for the quote - assuming of course that it's not something which has been falsely attributed to him.

Does anyone know when/where Kinnock originally uttered these words, if indeed he ever did?

Comment: +1 for a far more difficult question than it appears.  I hope my research leads someone else to a primary source...

Answer (score 4):

I've hunted high and low for the source of this quote for a while, even before seeing this question. I *think* the exact 'fortunate in her enemies' quote was used in the BBC tribute [*Margaret Thatcher: Prime Minister*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01s4f88) shown at 8PM on April 8th - probably around the end of the hour-and-a-half-long programme. After the programme ended, at 9:30, there were [five tweets posted](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22kinnock%22%20%22thatcher%22%20fortunate&src=typed_query&f=live) in fairly quick succession which contain references to the quote. Unfortunately, I've been unable to obtain a copy of that programme, so I can't be 100% sure.

On the other hand, I *have* found a very similar quote by Kinnock in the second episode of the 1993 TV series *[Thatcher: The Downing Street Years](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b0395lpc)*, entitled 'Best of Enemies'. This episode is available on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/hdvlSEHSDLM?t=1642).

> The greatest gift that Mrs. Thatcher has had, is in having the right
> enemies. Galtieri was a good enemy to have. A fascist dictator. I
> would like such enemies. Arthur Scargill was a good enemy to have.
> Because he didn't have a ballot. Because he tried to excuse illegal
> actions. The script was written for the Conservatives by that.

Comment: As noted in the other answer's comments, I found a reference to the quote (but no citation as to where it came from) in a 2005 book ('The strange death of Tory England' by Geoffrey Wheatcroft) which pre-dates the funeral by at least 8 years (probably longer given publishing timelines).

Comment: @pwaring I've managed to find the source of the quote above - it appeared in a 1993 BBC miniseries. Looks like this could indeed be the original?

Answer (score 2):

It is surprisingly difficult to find an original source for that quote.  There are *many* references to it in news reports in relation to Margaret Thatcher's funeral, which Lord Kinnock did not attend (in favor of a previously scheduled funeral).  Instead, he put out a radio tribute that he had recorded in advance, which seems to be what all the news reports are referencing. However, trying to track down the actual text of it is painful.

I finally found an excerpt of it [here](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/blog/2013/apr/08/miliband-clegg-local-elections-cameron-madrid), in a timeline of news of the day.  Her death is announced [at 12.49pm](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/blog/2013/apr/08/miliband-clegg-local-elections-cameron-madrid#block-5162aeaf95cbda4ff70e21e5), Kinnock makes a statement [at 3.30pm](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/blog/2013/apr/08/miliband-clegg-local-elections-cameron-madrid#block-5162d47895cbda4ff70e221b).   However, the quote in question is from a pre-recorded segment to be used when she died, which was released by Radio 4 around [6.21pm](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/blog/2013/apr/08/miliband-clegg-local-elections-cameron-madrid#block-5162f88095cbf15b0baf4302).  Unfortunately, **the phrase is not part of that excerpt**, and I can't even confirm for a fact that it is just an excerpt (except by comparison: a few other things on that page say "in full") .

I'm continuing to look for a full quote.

**Update:** I think [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01rqnj1#programme-broadcasts) is the radio program where the quote is supposed to have come from, but it's not available to listen to (at least for me).  If someone in the UK can give it a try and see whether they can listen to it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Worth noting: He would not be the first to use that phrase in relation to Thatcher.  There's a political book [from 2008](http://books.google.com/books?id=HKYpwbEuk5kC&lpg=PA162&ots=GZasCMJDU2&dq=%22fortunate%20in%20her%20enemies%22&pg=PA162#v=onepage&q=%22fortunate%20in%20her%20enemies%22&f=false) which uses it,  for instance, and I think I've seen one or two other references that predate her death.  Sir Bernard Ingham [said, upon her death](http://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/390414/Margaret-Thatcher-was-a-true-one-off-who-earned-the-respect-of-the-nation), "It is often said" about the phrase.

Comment: I'm wondering if Kinnock had used the quote before the funeral, and was just repeating it (I'm fairly sure I'd heard of it before her death).

I've also found another reference to it in 'The strange death of Tory England' by Geoffrey Wheatcroft (2005).

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of it in relation to him that *wasn't* in relation to her funeral message.  Although he did record it ahead of time (if that radio program actually contains the quote).